# Variable not expanding properly inside windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script which checks for the presence of environment variable MY_VAR and if Not set then it tries to get hold of the 1st argument passed to the script.
It then removes it quotes if present (") and then removes the trailing slash (/).

I have enabled extensions via `setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS` as my env variable `MY_VAR` can have spaces in its value and hence in order to use IF with DEFINED i need to enable extensions.

However, my whole program seems to not behave properly.

```
@echo off

cd %~dp0

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

@REM if MY_VAR Is defined then it can have spaces

if not defined MY_VAR ( 
    IF [%1] == [] goto :doSomething

    set ARG1=%1
    echo "Script is invoked with argument %ARG1%"
    set ARG1=%ARG1:"=%  
    
    :doSomething
    echo "I will do something"

    IF [%1]==[] (
        echo "Do  more things1"
    ) ELSE (
        echo "Do  more things2"
    )
)
else (
    IF [%1]==[] (
        echo "Do  more things3"
    ) ELSE (
        echo "Do  more things4"
    )
)
endlocal
```

I am invoking this as below

```
C:\>cmd /c call "C:\mydir\test2.bat" "c:\myDir sgds\"
```

The output is as below

```
"ARG1 is set to  "
"I will do something"
"Do  more things2"
```

Why ARG1 is NOT set properly by below code lines?

```
set ARG1=%1
echo "ARG1 is set to  %ARG1%"
```

Comment: Labels cannot appear in a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)

Comment: @Magoo : Did you try running my code? It doesn't complain about any label.

Comment: No - it won't complain. The label breaks the `for` loop. `cmd` then continues to the line after the label (if/else in uppercase), ignores the `)` and then complains about the `else`.

Comment: @Magoo : can you see the updated code? I am not clear why ARG1 isn't set properly. Doesn't look like the label is the culprit. Can you have a look?

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

REM if MY_VAR Is defined then it can have spaces

SET "arg1=%1"

if defined MY_VAR ( 
   IF [%1]==[] (
       echo "Do  more things3"
   ) ELSE (
       echo "Do  more things4"
   )
) ELSE (
 echo "Script is invoked with argument %ARG1%"
 IF DEFINED arg1 (
  set "ARG1=%ARG1:"=%"
  ECHO quotes are removed ARG1="!arg1!"
  IF "!arg1:~-1!"=="/" SET "ARG1=!arg1:~0,-1!"
  ECHO with terminal slash removed ARG1="!arg1!"
 )
 echo "I will do something with "!arg1!"
)
ENDLOCAL

GOTO :EOF
```

Beware of the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

Note the use of `!var!` after invoking `enabledelayedexpansion`. `%var%` within a *code block* will be resolved to the value of `var` when the code block is encountered. `!var!` (after invoking `enabledelayedexpansion`) will be resolved to the value of `var` as it is changed within the block.